# How to restart the Hyperledger Composer Playground locally

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I've followed the [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html) on how to install the Hyperledger Composer & Playground locally and it works.  However, if I reboot my computer and want to restart the Hyperledger Composer playground, I don't see how to do it, other than re-downloading the docker images and starting over from scratch.

How can you restart the playground it as to pick back up where you left off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Mac** then just follow these steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Type this command and press enter: `./composer.sh`

That's it. Now Hyperledger composer will locally re-started.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the docker-compose.yml in order to start where you left off,
otherwise your data will be lost after reboot. See http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html and the section called "A Note on Data Persistence" which provides more detail on this.

After reboot you just need to go to dir fabric-tools:

1. run ./startFabric.sh
2. run composer-playground

Answer (score 1):

If you had followed the tutorial, your system would have already downloaded all the required docker images.

```
docker images
```

command would show you all the images downloaded. 
You need to just go to fabric-dev-servers folder and then start the network using

```
./teardownFabric.sh
./startFabric.sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

Then verify that all dockers are running using command

```
docker ps
```

Then you can simply start composer playgroup by

```
composer-playground
```

Head to http://localhost:8080